# ios8 swift: how can i access/edit/remove default/private inputAccessoryView height constraint '_UIKBAutolayoutHeightConstraint'

Tags: swift, ios8, uikeyboard, nslayoutconstraint, inputaccessoryview

I would like to make inputAccessoryView expandable as the UITextView inside grows. 
inputAccessoryView has a 
private NSLayoutConstraint with identifier '_UIKBAutolayoutHeightConstraint'

that I cannot access, despite going through every constraint in inputAccessoryView.constraints array. I tried two methods:

```
 var constraints:[NSLayoutConstraint] = tableView.inputAccessoryView!.constraints() as Array
        for  (c: NSLayoutConstraint) in constraints{
            if c.identifier == "_UIKBAutolayoutHeightConstraint"{
                println("height")
            }
        }



var constraints:[NSLayoutConstraint] = tableView.inputAccessoryView!.constraints() as Array
        for  (c: NSLayoutConstraint) in constraints{
            if c.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttribute.Height{
                println("height constraint found")
            }
        }
```

Comment: show your code here.

Comment: code is irrelevant, you either know the answer or not. I added the code anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. I was searching for it in ViewDidLoad before the default constraint was setup.

Comment: How did you end up solving this?